# How to open "Recources" window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, resources, android-studio

I'm learning how to develop in *Android Studio* now and i have a problem.

I want to open *Resources Window* (like on a screenshot, link on it is placed below), but not by using button "A" in window of activity editor. May be some Hot-Key, or it is hidden in menus.

If i just open some resources in Project Window (for example strings.xml) i see just xml editor. I have no *Design* button at the bottom of the window. And in *View*->*Tool* window submenu *Design* is disabled.

Do any one have idea?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLFXp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings there will be no design tab.Only files in Layouts only have the design tab.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to open that window is to click on that '3 dots button' on an 'text' property.